# Server side paging with grouping

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-web-api, ag-grid

I have an angular 4 UI, web API and SQL server in the back-end. I use a third party grid from ag grid (https://www.ag-grid.com/).

Here are some info about my scenario :

1. I have total 1 million records in SQL server
2. I need to group the data based on user selection from the UI. Typically, after the grouping, the number of records to fetch from DB becomes something around 200 thousands.

3.User will do some filtering from the UI as well which makes the number of records to fetch will become something around 4000 to 5000.

4. I implemented paging (page size 100) at server side. I send offset and number of records to fetch from DB . The problem in this case is, since it is a huge data , my grouping at the database takes 15 seconds to finish which is quite a lot of time.
5. Another approach I tried is, get the paged data from DB without grouping and do the grouping in the API which is kind of finishing in milliseconds. The problem here is, I am showing some values in the UI based on groups such as count and sum of the some fields , the data shown in the currently fetched data might not be correct/complete as the the current group may span to the other pages in the DB which are not fetched yet.

Any recommendations to deal with this kind of scenario would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do most users really want/need to look through 200 thousand records? Perhaps more filters on what they want before you return data.

Comment: Your 5th approach doesn't work correctly as you mentioned, your performance bottleneck is database, which is bad, because it should be the last thing where slowness's appear, i can suggest you to look into **indexes configuration**, **results caching** or maybe you have a way to **reduce the initial set of data** somehow.

Comment: @Mathias , they actually deal with 4000 to 5000 rows of data after the grouping and filtering.